# BLUEs of angles of triangle

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

Let $\beta _1, \beta _2, \beta _3$ be the true value of the interior angle of a triangle. Let $Y_1,Y_2, Y_3$ are independent measurement of $\beta _1, \beta _2, \beta _3$ respectively. Assume that $Y_i$ is normally distributed with mean $\beta _i$ and variance $\sigma ^2$ for $i=1,2,3$ where $\sigma$ is unknown. Obtain $BLUEs$ of $\beta _1, \beta _2, \beta _3$ based on the measurements.

Comment: What's a blue?${}{}{}$

Comment: BLUE is Best Linear Unbiased Estimator.

Comment: useful link: http://www.gaussianwaves.com/2014/07/best-linear-unbiased-estimator-blue-introduction/

Comment: @MANMAID What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

As your question stands you have independent observations $Y_i \sim \text{N}(\beta_i, \sigma^2)$.  There is no relevance to the contextual statement that these are angles of a triangle, since you have already given the full joint distribution of the observable values.  With this distributional formulation the *only* linear unbiased estimators are $\hat{\beta_i} = y_i$, and these each have variance $\sigma^2$.  Hence, these are the BLUEs.

Perhaps you intended to formulate this question in a way that brings in the triangular aspect?